# Get element which is in the recursion angular4?

Tags: angular, recursion

I have a component as shown and I generated the structure using recursion

```
<component>
   <div class="a">
   <component>
      <div class="a">
         <component>
             <div class="a"></div>
         </component>
      </div>
    </component>
    </div>
</component>
```

In each instance of the component(in `ngAfterViewInit` or `ngAfterViewChecked`), I want to get the element with class `a` which is specific to that particular instance. I don't want the class `a` element which is belongs to parent or child instance. How can I get the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ElementRef. You reference the component itself and then find it's children like so:

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...
    const classA = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.a');
}
```

Comment: +1. notice the above selector is for any element with class `a` to be more precise, you can `nativeElement.querySelector('div.a')`

Comment: My functionality is different but I did everything just because of this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewChild to have the instances separately

```
@ViewChild('one') one : ComponentClass;
@ViewChild('two') two : ComponentClass;
@ViewChild('three') three : ComponentClass;
```

HTML should look like

```
<component #one>
   <div class="a">
   <component #two>
      <div class="a">
         <component #three>
             <div class="a"></div>
         </component>
      </div>
    </component>
    </div>
</component>
```

So you can have the instances `ngAfterViewInit` by `console.log` you can identify as below

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.one) 
  console.log(this.two)
  console.log(this.three)
}
```

Comment: How can I add different references when it is in recursion? I said recursion